# How to pass property value between to instances of a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have to datepicker components, from date and to date.

i want to update the to date with the from date if the to date is empty.

I've looked at doing emit on the value but feel this is not right and i'm not sure how to do it

```
 <datepicker
      input-label="From"
      input-id="start-date"
      input-name="start_date"
      input-value="<%= group_discount.start_date %>"
      @change-date="changeDate"
      >
 </datepicker>
 <datepicker
        input-label="To"
        input-id="end-date"
        input-name="end_date"
        input-value="<%= group_discount.end_date %>">
 </datepicker>


import Vue from "vue"
import Datepicker from "../components/DatePicker"

Vue.use(Datepicker)

const initGroupDiscount = () => {
  new Vue({
  el: "#js-group-discounts",
  components: {
   Datepicker,
  },
  methods: {
   changeDate(value) {
    console.log("value")
    console.log(value)
    },
  },
 })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  initGroupDiscount()
})





    <template>
       <div >
        <label :for="this.inputId">{{ this.inputLabel }}</label>
        <input  type="text"
                class="form-control form-control-info"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
                :name="this.inputName"
                :id="this.inputId"
                pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
                required
                v-model="isInput"
                v-on:keyup="updateCalendar($event)"
                ref="dateinput"
                @blur="blur"
                @focus="focus">
        <datepicker format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    input-class="form-control"
                    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
                    v-model="isPicker"
                    :inline="true"
                    v-show="isOpen"
                    @mouseover.native="mouseOver"
                    @mouseleave.native="mouseLeave"
                    @selected="updateInput"></datepicker>
      </div>
    </template>

     <script>
     import Vue from "vue"
     import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker"
     Vue.use(Datepicker)

export default {
    name: "neptune-datepicker",
    props: {
        inputLabel: {
            type: String,
        },
        inputId: {
            type: String,
        },
        inputValue: {
            type: String,
        },
        inputName: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    data(){
        let value = ""
        if (this.inputValue) {
            const dateParts = this.inputValue.split("-")
            value =`${dateParts[2]}/${dateParts[1]}/${dateParts[0]}`
        }

        return {
            isInput: value,
            isPicker: this.inputValue,
            isOpen: false,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Datepicker
    },
    methods: {
        updateInput(date) {
            this.isInput = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
            this.$emit('changeDate', this.isInput);
        },
        updateCalendar(event) {
            const dateString = event.srcElement.value

            if (dateString.length === 10) {
                const dateParts = dateString.split("/")

                const dateObject = new Date(
                    dateParts[2],
                    dateParts[1],
                    dateParts[0],
                )

                if ((dateObject !== "Invalid Date") && !Number.isNaN(dateObject)) {
                    this.isPicker = dateObject
                }
            }
        },
        blur() {
            this.isOpen = false
        },
        focus() {
            this.$refs.dateinput.focus()
            this.isOpen = true
        },
        mouseOver() {
            this.$refs.dateinput.focus()
            this.isOpen = true
        },
        mouseLeave() {
            this.$refs.dateinput.focus()
            this.isOpen = true
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

it emits the correct value to the console but i don't know how i would pass this to only that particular instance of the component, the "To" date

Answer (score 0):

The parent component should pass a prop to both data sub-components:

```
<datepicker
  :myValue="myValue"
  input-label="From"
  input-id="start-date"
  input-name="start_date"
  input-value="<%= group_discount.start_date %>"
  @change-date="changeDate"
>
</datepicker>
<datepicker
    :myValue="myValue"
    input-label="To"
    input-id="end-date"
    input-name="end_date"
    input-value="<%= group_discount.end_date %>">
</datepicker>
```

Then you can use that prop in a computed or method to validate if it contains a value or not and override the to or from value.

Edit: You can also use your emit strategy but you still need to pass a prop to one of the components so it can read the data. If you've never used props before read about them here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: i've got it working. i did the emit as i above. then i assigned the data picker "To" a ref, i then used that ref to update a computed property which then sets the value of the "To" datepicker. Not sure if this is the best way